# Swift property wrappers on function arguments and initializers

Tags: swift, initializer, property-wrapper

I try to use new @propertyWrappers on arguments defined in type initializer like in the below code:

```
init(@Inject services: TodoServiceContainer? = nil) {
    service = services?.todoService
}
```

But Xcode doesn't compile such code and throws such error

> Closure captures '_services' before it is declared

Using the same property wrapper on function after initialization of object works great

```
func inject(@Inject services: TodoServiceContainer? = nil) {
        service = services?.todoService
}
```

Also if I comment usage of argument inside initializer body code compiles ok

```
init(@Inject services: TodoServiceContainer? = nil) {
    //service = services?.todoService
}
```

But I would like to use initializer argument inside body to initialize some properties

Is it even possible?

[image]